# Pivot Table Expecting '('

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM

(select

petID as pet,

sum(numpet) as numberofpets

from petTable) as base

pivot(

count(sum(numpet))

for petid IN ([1],[2],[3])

) AS pivottable
```

Been stuck on this syntax error for awhile :( it keeps saying incorrect syntax near 'numpet' and ([1],[2],[3]). Could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Which dB is this? Provide some information so that we can check

Answer (score 0):

1. You're missing a `GROUP BY petID` clause in the `base` derived table
2. You can't refer to the `numberofpets` field as `sum(numpet)`. Just do `COUNT(numberofpets)`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by GROUP by clause in the base derived table?

Comment: Run the query in that derived table by itself, the error you will get is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Use missed GROUP BY in your physical table SELECT clause :

```
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT petID as pet,sum(numpet) as numberofpets
    FROM petTable
    GROUP BY petID 
  ) base
  pivot
  (
    COUNT(SUM(numpet)) FOR petid IN ([1],[2],[3])
  ) AS pivottable
```